# Kickstart install problems, ethernet configuration missing

Tags: centos, networking, kickstart

Using CentOS 6.7 I've created a custom(and working) kickstart installation. Initially I had coded the configuration for eth0 in the kickstart file, but ideally I'd like the user to input it, but it seems whatever I do, I'm not getting to the configuration screen for networking.

This what I used to have
`network --onboot=yes --device eth0 --bootproto static --ip=10.1.2.3 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --noipv6 --hostname=somename`
I've tried leaving it blank with just "network" and I've tried omitting it altogether and a few other things, but no luck.

How do I get the network configuration to appear? Any advice?

My ks.cfg, %package and %post sections omitted.

`interactive
lang en_US.UTF-8
timezone --utc Europe/Oslo
network --onboot=yes --device eth0 --bootproto static --ip=10.1.2.3 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --noipv6 --hostname=somename
hostname=somename
rootpw somepass
user --name=un --password=somepass
firewall --disabled
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
selinux --disabled
bootloader --location=mbr driveorder=sda --append="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
clearpart --all
part /boot --fstype=ext4 --asprimary --size=500
part pv.008002 --grow --size=200
volgroup vg_st --pesize=4096 pv.008002
logvol swap --name=lv_swap --vgname=vg_st --size=8192
logvol / --fstype=ext4 --name=lv_root --vgname=vg_st --grow --size=200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the default behaviour for kickstart installs, [per the docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html):

```
 You will only be prompted for information about your network:

   * before fetching the kickstart file if you are using the
     asknetwork boot option
   * when the network is first accessed once the kickstart
     file has been fetched, if the network was not used to fetch
     it and you have provided no kickstart network commands
```

How is the kickstart file being supplied? The asknetwork boot option might be one option (see link in linked docs), or to not fight kickstart on this point and put the IP address configuration information into e.g. a DHCP server, or to provide a hostname to the boot options, that a kickstart script can then try to do DNS lookups on to get the necessary static details, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that sort of works. It gives me an early option to specify IP and such, but it doesn't give me the nice GUI that's usually part of the installation, also it doesn't seem to honor the hostname setting in the ks.cfg file anymore. Providing DHCP is not an option as this will be deployed in many different environments, some without any DHCP servers. I provide the kickstart file in my isolinux.cfg like so:  `append initrd=initrd.img ks=file:ks.cfg asknetwork`. I embed this all into an ISO image.

Comment: Humm, scratch that. The generated ifcfg-eth0 has the IP information I provided, but still has BOOTPROTO=dhcp. The IP address eth0 shows up with in ifconfig is an entirely different one, and it's not one of the IPs the DHCP server would provide.

Comment: Seems I fudged that with some settings still left in the kickstart file. I'll stick to this solution since it seems to work, just not as elegant as the normal network configuration. I can just set the hostname in the post install, and I'm all set.